# Web deployment project help

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, projects

Where can I get a complete reference about Web Deployment Projects 2008?

I have searched for it, but it appears that there are only blogs posts or forums questions about WDP specific characteristics.

Comment: i suspect that there is any documentation available on deployment projects ? what aspect are you specifically looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's a single source of docs for WDP. [The ScottGu blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx) has the most information and links to the [blog post with more info about how they work in the 2005 version](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/06/429723.aspx), which is basically the same as 2008.

There's not really much to them that isn't covered in the blog posts (I think build events is the only thing, and those are standard MSBuild concepts, so you can find those around). Is there a specific problem you're having with them or goal you're trying to achieve?